# How to evaluate the change of information of a random variable?

Tags: random-variables, entropy

Given a random variable $X$ having finite alphabet $\mathcal{A}_X$ and valid $p_x(\cdot)$ (for which there is no $x_0 \in \mathcal{A}_X$ so that $p_x(x_0) = 0$) I want to know its actual outcome (speaking about sport, $X$ could be the team that would buy a really famous player: the experts would give me $\mathcal{A}_X$ and $p_x(\cdot)$).

I'm willing to pay a $V$ amount of money for this information and I've found someone who could help me. Before the closing of the deal I find out that the outcome of $X$ won't surely be, let's say, $x_0$.

Since prior this discovery the value of $X$ was $V$, what is the value $V^\star$ I should pay for the information?

**How I would do** - I would evaluate $H(X)$ using the definition, then I'd declare a new random variable $Y$ so that $\mathcal{A}_Y = \mathcal{A}_X \,/\, x_0$ and $p_Y(y) = \frac{p_x(y)}{1 - p_x(x_0)}$ and finally I'd evaluate $H(Y)$. Now I guess that $V^\star = \frac{H(Y)}{H(X)}V$.

I think this approach could be valid but I am not sure about that since it would be more natural to me to evaluate something like $H(X \,|\, X \neq x_0)$. Also, I'm not sure that a proportion is the way to go for finding $V^\star$.

Comment: It seems to me that you are actually computing "$H(X|X\neq x_0)$" with your approach (unless you mean something different by $H(X|X\neq x_0)$, which is an unconventional notation). Regarding $V^*$, this is essentially your own task to define how it is computed, however, the proportional approach seems certainly reasonable.

Comment: You can use Shannon's entropy law to calculate the information gain, but how much you should pay for the information is impossible to say.

Comment: @Stelios thank you, I was unsure if $H(X|X \leq x_0)$ was equivalent (somehow) to $H(Y)$: to my understanding the latter should be always less than the former since I thought it was reasonable to think that "knowing more" about a rv should lower its uncertanity (and entropy) but if $\mathcal{A}_X = \{A,B,C\}$ and $p_X(A)=0.9$, $p_X(B)=0.05$, $p_X(C)=0.05$ then $H(X) \simeq 0.57$. Removing $A$ from $X$ I get $Y$ and its entropy is $H(Y) = 1$, so $H(Y) > H(X)$. This means that the information I wanted to buy has "more value" now than before?

Comment: @GiulioScattolin Your example is correct and serves to show that entropy is not an appropriate metric for your purposes. Note that entropy provides information about a random variable *before* it is observed. In particular, a high entropy random variable is less easy to predict. Of course, since in your case you want to increase your chances to correctly predict, a higher entropy variable is not useful. Maybe you should consider a different measure of information?

Comment: @Stelios I agree with that, can you suggest me what to look for? BTW I also tried to evaluate the entropy of $Z$ where $A_Z=A_X/C$ and it turns out that $H(Z)\simeq 0.3<H(X)$. Actually this could make sense: the outcome is more predictable in the “ $Z$-situation ” than the “ $X$ ” one, so, if $V^{\star\star}$ is what I’d pay in the “ $Z$-situation ”, then: $V^{\star\star} < V < V^\star$ (and $H(Z) < H(X) < H(Y)$). If that’s is correct then it is just a matter of choosing $\mu : \text{entropy}\mapsto\text{value}$ so that $\mu(H(X))=V$ and so on. Does it make any sense? Thank you very much.

Comment: @GiulioScattolin Reading your problem again more carefully, the entropy is indeed a good indicator of what you should pay. For example, the "Y situation" is a maximum uncertainty case, therefore you should pay a lot for the information of which outcome will happen. In contrast, in the "Z-situation", it is highly probable to predict the outcome correctly and there is no incentive for you to pay a lot. Therefore, your question is essentially how to define a "payment rule". As I said, this is up to you. Maybe there are similar works out there that consider this, but I am no expert.

Comment: @Stelios I've updated the original question adding the example and the observations made here. Thank you very much indeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's investigate if *entropy* can be a reasonable measure for this usage. Consider a rv $X$ whose alphabet is $\mathcal{A}_X = \{ \alpha, \beta, \gamma \}$ and $p_X(\alpha) = 0.9$, $p_X(\beta) = 0.05$ and $p_X(\gamma) = 0.05$. The *entropy* of $X$ defined as $$H(X) = -\sum_{x \in \mathcal{A}_X} p_X(x) \log_2(p_X(x))$$ gives $H(X) \simeq 0.57$. For example, let's say we're sure $\alpha$ won't be the outcome of $X$, we define $Y$ as stated in the question and evaluate its entropy obtaining $H(Y) = 1$. Considering another situation, this time $\gamma$ won't be the outcome of $X$ and if we define $Z$ as said above we get $H(Z) \simeq 0.3$.

In the initial scenario $\alpha$ is the most likely outcome, *almost* certain. If we remove that outcome we're left with no more than a coin toss, the *worst* case scenario: our knowledge about $X$ is *actually* lower than before (we thought we were *almost* certain about the outcome - not entirely sure) and now we're left with a 50-50 decision. Knowing the exact outcome now is more *valuable* than knowing it before - this is represented by the fact that $H(Y) > H(X)$.

On the other hand, removing $\gamma$ from the possible outcomes increases the probability that $\alpha$ will be the real outcome, lowering the uncertainty of the scenario and the value of the information I wanted to buy - confirmed by $H(Z) < H(X)$.

This example seems to agree that *entropy* is a reasonable measure for this usage.